# Disable snapshots for EBS

Tags: amazon-web-services

I spin up a m4.4xlarge for a dedicated task once a day for a few hours.  I don't need a snapshot of the EBS volume and am looking to cut costs, - is there some way to disable it?  Also is there anything i need to consider when doing this?

Thanks,

Comment: Please provide more info:

Do you start/stop the instance every day? Or launch/terminate?

Do you need to persist data from day to day?
Do you automate anything with this instance? If yes, what tools do you use?

Comment: AWS does not automatically take EBS snapshots. If you aren't doing something to initiate snapshot creation, then snapshots will not be created. From a purely cost savings perspective, your solution is simply to not take snapshots.

Comment: Thanks for the replies.  The machine is actually setup via a 3rd party tool so i would have to modify the cloudformation template.  I was however expecting to find somewhere in the web UI to disable snapshots but a google search wasn't bringing anything up..